# DataFrame timeseries indexing with own date-time data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some pressure, temperature and humidity data over a date-time series (i.e. columns: date, time, pressure, temp, humidity). I would like to set up a function that gives me the average and std of these three parameters within a certain date and time(inputs). So far i have managed to import the data into a dataframe and define the variables temp, press, and humid as the columns in the dataframe. I'm pretty stuck trying to figure out how I'm going to connect the date-time(inputs) to the other three data columns. any ideas? I have read through the pandas doc and it just confuses me... because it always creates its own time-date column series. =/

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

def TempPressHumid(time_start, time_end, date_start, date_end, df1):

    temp = df1[date_start:date_end]
    temp = df1.between_time(time_start,time_end)

    out = {'temp_avg':np.mean(temp['temp']),
    'temp_std':np.std(temp['temp']),
    'press_avg':np.mean(temp['press']),
    'press_std':np.std(temp['press']),
    'humid_avg':np.mean(temp['humid']),
    'humid_std':np.std(temp['humid'])}
    print out

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('TM4CVC.csv')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'temp': df['Ch2_Value'],
    'press':df['Ch3_Value'],
    'humid':df['Ch1_Value']})
    # want to add my time and date index here? 


TempPressHumid(time_start = '08:29:19', time_end = '08:29:19', 
               date_start = '2012-06-25', date_end = '2012-06-025', df1 = df1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest converting your dates and times into datetimes, that way your date and time columns become one column,  then set that new datetime column as the index of the dataframe then you should be able to do a selection based on your interval.

(just off the top of my head you may be able to concatenate the date and time columns into a string and then use the dateutils parser to change that string into a datetime - there may be a simpler way but I haven't spent much time (pun intended))